# I want to extract all method names and variable names from a java source file using ANTLR4

Tags: java, extract, antlr, grammar, antlr4

> Basically I want to extract all variable names, irrespective of their
>   scope. And all function/method names inside the source code.

For the given input,

```
     class temp{
         int a;

    public static void main(String args[]){
    int b = 0;
temp ob = new temp();
temp.printob();

    }

void printob(){
System.out.print("-");
}
        }
```

The output should be something like:

> variables = {"a","b","ob"}
>
> methods = {"main","printob"}

Comment: ANTLR is a parser generator, so you cannot use it *directly* for this task, but you could certainly use it to generate a program to do the job.  This would require writing a grammar definition in ANTLR format.  The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) provides all the details you'll need for that, including a complete formal grammar (albeit probably not in a form you can use directly).  As for this SO question, however, it's unclear what your actual question is.

Comment: I am new to ANTLR, so basically I wanted to know what is the right way and how can I use ANTLR do achieve this. If you can shed more light on that it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A parser generator such as ANTLR is one kind of program that generates source code for other programs.  Basically, you feed ANTLR input describing the language (i.e. Java) that the desired program must parse, and it produces a program to do the parsing.  But Java's is a pretty complex grammar, and not at all the kind of thing I would recommend to a newcomer not only to ANTLR itself, but (it seems) more generally to parser generators overall.

Comment: In any case, your question is far too broad to be answered here.  We field questions about specific, tightly scoped programming problems, not broad-based "how to" questions.

Comment: Thanks. Anyways I was able figure out a way to get it done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is making small changes to the grammar specification of the said language in this case Java.

What we can do is create a global arraylist and insert all identifiers into it.

In the grammar, for each rule wherever Identifier is used for example,

```
methodcall : return_types IDENTIFIER LEFTPAREN params RIGHTPAREN;
```

we will make the following changes(where our global arraylist is called all_identifiers)

```
methodcall : return_types IDENTIFIER LEFTPAREN params RIGHTPAREN{

 all_identifiers.add($IDENTIFIER);

};
```

similarly adding the above code, to each rule having Identifier we will be able to extract all the methods and variable names (if you want them in different arraylists create two arraylist one for method calls and one for variable declaration)

Additional Note:

When I originally posted this question I wanted to find a way to change all method call names and all variable names to some pre-defined names to normalise the code.
For example in the code I wanted to change int a,b,c; to something like int varbl,varbl,varbl; and similarly for methods I wanted to change all method names to mthd.

So the best way I found to achieve this was,
1. Identify all rules, where we want to change some Identifier
2. In each of the rule add similar code section (this step needs to be done as token object by it self is not editable so we type cast it to CommonToken object which gives us ability to set the test using setText() method.)

```
{
 CommonToken tkn_tmp = $IDENTIFIER;
 tkn_tmp.setText("varbl"); 
 // or if it's a method rule 
 //tkn_tmp.setText("mthd");
 }
```

3. Now all the tokens will be changed from their original form to the value we are setting in.

4. After this you need to parse the input code through the grammar, and the parse tree along with parser text will be updated(along with token start and token end pointers)

There is another way to achieve the same, which is by iterating through all the tokens sequentially and adding adding token in an arrylist, and checking for token type. If the token type is Identifier change the text to whatever you want to, and then as usual append it to the array list.

For segregation of method names and variable names you might need to change the grammar so that, variable Identifier and method Identifier are differentiable.